# Is there a name for

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for a section of text which is delimited by final punctuation, regardless of whether it is a sentence, clause, phrase or single word?  In other words, a term that generalizes all of the following:
"Really?",  "A very large one!",  "I wish I could have known...",  "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

Comment: These are all sentences, even though some are indeed also single words, phrases, and/or clauses.

Answer (score 1):

All sections of text delimited by final punctuation are sentences. Merriam-Webster's definition of a sentence is "a word, clause, or phrase or a group of clauses or phrases forming a syntactic unit which expresses an assertion, a question, a command, a wish, an exclamation, or the performance of an action, that in writing usually begins with a capital letter and concludes with appropriate end punctuation, and that in speaking is distinguished by characteristic patterns of stress, pitch, and pauses" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentence).